# Syntax Error(missing operator) in query expression - MS-Access

Tags: ms-access, syntax, operator-keyword

This doesn't produce syntax errors but it gives wrong arguments error:

```
SELECT left(
  [aname],
 IIF(instr([aname], " ") = 0 AND instr([aname], ",") = 0,
   Len(FinalForgotten.aname),
  IIF(instr([aname], ",") = 0,
    InStr(1,[aname]," ")-1,
    InStr(1,[aname],",")-1)))
&  ","  &

right(
   [aname],
 IIF(instr([aname], " " = 0 AND instr([aname], ",") = 0,
   Len(FinalForgotten.aname),
    IIF(instr([aname], ",") = 0,
      Len(aname)-InStr(1,[aname]," "),
      Len(aname)-InStr(1,[aname],",")))))
 &  " " &

defense_final.middle_initial AS fullname INTO FinalForgottenWithMiddle
FROM FinalForgotten INNER JOIN defense_final ON (right(FinalForgotten.aname,
 IIF(instr([aname], ",") = 0,
 Len(FinalForgotten.aname)-InStr(1,FinalForgotten.[aname]," "),
 Len(FinalForgotten.aname)-InStr(1,FinalForgotten.[aname],",")
  )
 )=defense_final.first_name) AND (left(FinalForgotten.aname,
IIF(instr([aname], ",") = 0,
  InStr(1,FinalForgotten.[aname]," ")-1,
  InStr(1,FinalForgotten.[aname],",")-1
    )
)=defense_final.last_name);
```

So adding the extra arguments I now get syntax error "Missing ), ], or Item in query expression" :

```
   SELECT left(
  [aname],
 IIF(instr([aname], " ") = 0 AND instr([aname], ",") = 0,
   Len(FinalForgotten.aname),
  IIF(instr([aname], ",") = 0,
    InStr(1,[aname]," ")-1,
    InStr(1,[aname],",")-1)))
&  ","  &

right(
   [aname],
 IIF(instr([aname], " ") = 0 AND instr([aname], ",") = 0,
   Len(FinalForgotten.aname),
    IIF(instr([aname], ",") = 0,
      Len(aname)-InStr(1,[aname]," "),
      Len(aname)-InStr(1,[aname],","))))
 &  " " &

defense_final.middle_initial AS fullname INTO FinalForgottenWithMiddle
FROM FinalForgotten INNER JOIN defense_final ON 

left(FinalForgotten.aname,
   IIF(instr([aname], " ") = 0 AND instr([aname], ",") = 0,
      Len(FinalForgotten.aname),
      IIF(instr([aname], ",") = 0,
        InStr(1,FinalForgotten.[aname]," ")-1,
        InStr(1,FinalForgotten.[aname],",")-1)))

 =defense_final.last_name AND 

 right(FinalForgotten.aname,
      IIF(instr([aname], " ") = 0 AND instr([aname], ",") = 0,
      Len(FinalForgotten.aname),
       IIF(instr([aname], ",") = 0,
        Len(FinalForgotten.aname)-InStr(1,FinalForgotten.[aname]," "),
        Len(FinalForgotten.aname)-InStr(1,FinalForgotten.[aname],","))))

=defense_final.first_name;
```

Any workaround?

Thanks for response.

Comment: may I suggest that you give your table a SHORT (1 letter) alias, and update your question ? This would make it more readable I think.

Comment: you mention "wrong arguments error". Can you specify the error ? Usually that comes when a field is misspelled.

Comment: @iDevlop It says "wrong number of arguments used with function in query expression 'left(..."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be easier to put that logic into VBA functions so your query looks like this

```
SELECT GetFullNameWithMiddle([aname]) AS fullname
INTO FinalForgottenWithMiddle
FROM FinalForgotten INNER JOIN defense_final
    ON GetLastName([aname])=defense_final.last_name
    AND GetFirstName([aname])=defense_final.first_name
```

Since you say you don't want to use VBA, try this instead.  I enclosed every

```
InStr(x, y) = 0
```

in parentheses, so

```
IIf(InStr(x, y) = 0 AND InStr(p, q) = 0, g, h)
```

becomes

```
IIf((InStr(x, y) = 0) AND (InStr(p, q) = 0), g, h)
```

Making that change allowed me to switch into the query design grid, which means that the SQL parser liked it:

```
SELECT left(
    [aname],
    IIF((instr([aname], " ") = 0) AND (instr([aname], ",") = 0),
    Len(FinalForgotten.aname),
    IIF((instr([aname], ",") = 0),
    InStr(1,[aname]," ")-1,
    InStr(1,[aname],",")-1)))

    &  ","  &

right(
    [aname],
    IIF((instr([aname], " ") = 0) AND (instr([aname], ",") = 0),
    Len(FinalForgotten.aname),
    IIF((instr([aname], ",") = 0),
      Len(aname)-InStr(1,[aname]," "),
      Len(aname)-InStr(1,[aname],","))))

    &  " " &

defense_final.middle_initial AS fullname INTO FinalForgottenWithMiddle
FROM FinalForgotten INNER JOIN defense_final ON 

left(FinalForgotten.aname,
    IIF((instr([aname], " ") = 0) AND (instr([aname], ",") = 0),
    Len(FinalForgotten.aname),
    IIF((instr([aname], ",") = 0),
    InStr(1,FinalForgotten.[aname]," ")-1,
    InStr(1,FinalForgotten.[aname],",")-1)))

=defense_final.last_name AND 

right(FinalForgotten.aname,
    IIF((instr([aname], " ") = 0) AND (instr([aname], ",") = 0),
    Len(FinalForgotten.aname),
    IIF((instr([aname], ",") = 0),
    Len(FinalForgotten.aname)-InStr(1,FinalForgotten.[aname]," "),
    Len(FinalForgotten.aname)-InStr(1,FinalForgotten.[aname],","))))

=defense_final.first_name;
```

Comment: Not for me. I'm not too good with VB. I was hoping to stick with sql.

Comment: The VBA environment does a much better job at telling you where syntax errors are.  And the VBA to do what you're doing here is far simpler than the SQL statement you've constructed.  But each to his own.  If I had to do this with SQL then I would use LIKE rather than InStr (`[aname] LIKE "* *"` will give the same result as `InStr([aname], " ") > 0`).  I was playing a bit with your query as edited and I think you may just need to make sure you have parentheses everywhere.  See the newly-edited answer for a suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

line 10

```
right(
```

has no corresponding right parenthesis

Comment: Thanks for reply but I add a right parenthesis but then get a syntax error that says "Missing ), ], or Item in query expression" and it places the cursor on the first AND.

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT left( [aname],`
 So [aname] is a text field.

```
 IIF(instr([aname], " ") = 0 AND instr([aname], ",") = 0,
```

If this condition is true you want the length of the Left String to be:

```
 FinalForgotten.aname,
```

Which is not an integer. You want:

```
SELECT left(
  [aname],
 IIF(instr([aname], " ") = 0 AND instr([aname], ",") = 0,
   Len(FinalForgotten.aname),
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 IIF(instr([aname], " " = 0 AND instr([aname], ",") = 0,
```

on line 12 should be

```
 IIF(instr([aname], " ") = 0 AND instr([aname], ",") = 0,
```

Comment: It still gives error "Missing ), ], or Item in query expression"